# Set cookie expire date - Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I was trying to create a cookie with a defined expiration date. Here's my code:

```
function setCookie(){
  var date=new Date();
  date.setFullYear(2015);
  document.cookie="cookie_name=tracking_true; expires=" +date.toUTCString() + ";";
}
```

When I check into my browser (from Google Chrome console I type: document.cookie), I can find only this: cookie_name=tracking_true. I cannot find the expires date. Do you have any idea why I cannot see the exiperes date?

Thanks,
Alessio

Answer (score 2):

`document.cookie` displays only the cookie names.  To see other parameters, in Chrome, use developer tools, resources tab, then cookies.  In Firebug, use the cookies tab.  There is documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie